# When Must a Float be Cleared?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have some question about when floated elements need and don't need to be cleared.

Consider the following markup:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <a href="#">Delete Destination</a>
    </div>
    Unfloated text here.
</div>
```

This seems to work correctly, although I never clear the floated content. Does this markup have potential problems?

Comment: http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/floats/enclosing-floats.php

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the text would move it down underneath your "Delete destination".

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear

Comment: Okay, right. So you don't see any problems with what I'm doing?

Comment: What problems do you expect? Your text will use up the space that the floating div isn't using. The rest of the text will go to next line.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm setting a float style. I guess it's limited to the element in which the style occurs. For some reason, I'd had it in my head that floats must specifically be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember school days, when you needed to go to the next line?

Whenever you want to go the next line, you gotta clear the floats. But the difference in CSS and browser world is that, next line may be 500px down :). Whenever you want to continue having elements on the same line, then don't clear the floats.

This is of course very basic explanation. Please let me know if I can help more.